# Change set TimePicker view to spinner mode programatically

Tags: java, android, timepicker

How to I change the TimePicker's mode to Spinner dynamically?

I am trying to add a TimePicker view to my LinearLayout inside a Dialog. However, when I instantiate a TimePicker instance, it has no methods such as `setTimePickerMode()`. I know I can do this in the XML file by setting the attribute, but I want to do it dynamically.

I use this line of code to add my TimePicker:

```
myLinearLayout.addView(new TimePicker(myDialog.getContext()));
```

It shows the default Clock style, but I want it to be in the spinner mode. I didn't use the `TimePickerDialog()` because I want it to be inside my LinearLayout, not a independent dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to do something like that

```
myLinearLayout.addView(new TimePicker(new ContextThemeWrapper(myDialog.getContext(), android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_NoActionBar)));
```

Comment: I am getting an error, and how is that adding a TimePicker?

Comment: Thanks man it works, but it seems like the theme is deprecated, is there any other way to do this?